# Custom ThreadPool class implementation in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool

I have a task to create my custom Thread Pool, but I need to restrict him: only one task per time (lock construction). I have to create two classes MyThreadPool and MyTask. MyTask shall contain void Execute() method, MyThreadPool shall contain void Execute(MyTask task).

The problem is that I cannot implement MyThreadPool in a proper way: it runs either one task per time (without any multithreading) or runs all tasks (and lock construction doesn't help).

Please give me any suggestions on how can I implement classes. Espetially 'MyThreadPool', so it supports Mutlithreading, so 'MyThreadPool.Execute' without 'lock(locker)' runs several tasks and only one task per time with 'lock(locker)'.

Now my code looks like this

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace Task37.CustomThreadpool
{
    class Program
    {
        public static object locker = new object();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyTask[] myTasks = new MyTask[]
                {
                    new MyTask(Count),
                    new MyTask(Count),
                    new MyTask(Count)
                };

            for (int i = 0; i < myTasks.Length; i++)
            {
                MyThreadPool.Execute(myTasks[i]);
            }
        }

        public static void Count()
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
        }
    }

    public class MyTask
    {
        public ThreadStart threadStart;

        public MyTask(ThreadStart threadStart)
        {
            this.threadStart = threadStart;
        }
        public void Execute()
        {
            threadStart.Invoke();
        }
    }

    public static class MyThreadPool
    {
        public static object locker = new object();

        public static void Execute(MyTask myTask)
        {
            myTask.Execute();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't done anything with the `locker` instances you've created. Surely you meant to use them in a `lock(locker)` statement somewhere?

Comment: This code runs only one task at a time even without lock(locker). How can I implement MyThreadPoos so it supports Multithreading?

Comment: `it runs either one task per time` isn't that the same as `only one task per time (lock construction)`? I don't understand the issue.

Comment: You can take some inspiration from [here](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/ThreadPool.CoreCLR.cs,8449b4bfef11bfa3)

Comment: @mjwills 'it runs either one task per time' isn't that the same as 'only one task per time (lock construction)' - yes, it is the same. I am just trying to implement 'Execute(MyTask myTask)' in such a way, so it could run several tasks per time, and after adding 'lock(locker)' it shall run only one task per time

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @mjwills, just to better understand multithreading and improve my knowledge in c#

Comment: Let's say 7 executions are currently in flight, and then the lock is taken. What should happen?

Comment: @mjwills, it looks like nothing should happen, they are currently in flight.

Comment: @mjwills, thank you for your attention to my question :)

Comment: For better understanding of multithreading I would suggest this resource: [Threading in C#](http://www.albahari.com/threading/) by Joseph Albahari. Trying to implement a thread-pool from scratch is too advanced IMHO.

Comment: `it looks like nothing should happen, they are currently in flight` So the next request should block until the 7 finish? Or something else?

Comment: I can recommend to see the crude ThreadPool example in the Accelerated C# (2010) book by Trey Nash.

Comment: If a thread pool runs only one task at a time, then there's no need for a "pool" of threads. You can do it with just one thread.

Comment: I think you looking to implement a producer /consumer pattern. Look at BlockingCollection class. Here you can have multiple producers enqueueing tasks on the queue (in the execute method that should be renamed to queueforexecution) and returning when complete.  in a separate thread that you create start checking the queue for tasks and execute them sequentially on that separate thread (be sure to try/catch in case a task throws, else you going to have a que of pending tasks and no executions.-with this mechanism, no locks are required from your part, the collection will manage the concurrency